# Change the default command line startup location in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, command-line

I want to be able to open my command prompt from my desktop, for example, and have the default starting location be somewhere else, such as C:\

My question is how to I do this in windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

Normally most of the Google post might suggest you to change the string vale named Autorun in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor and it might cause some problems. As a simple work around.

- Copy the cmd.exe to desktop or some other place where you would not
  have permission problem.
- Right-click on the copied cmd.exe and select "properties". From
  "Shortcut" menu, change the "Start in:" directory to the desired C:\
  path

Comment: **Do not** copy the `cmd.exe` to any place... Just perform the second statement of the procedure on the `cmd.exe` in it's original location.